# MySQL PHP Member Page is Displaying all users on my table

Tags: php, mysql, session

**LOGIN FORM (login_form.php)**

```
<form action="checkuser.php" class="reg-page" method="post" name="" id="">
                <div class="reg-header">            
                    <h2>Client Login</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group" style="padding-bottom:20px">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" class="form-control">
                </div>                    
                <div class="input-group" style="padding-bottom:20px">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                </div>                    

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" name="submit" type="submit">Login</button>                        
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr>

                <h4>Forget your Password ?</h4>
                <p>no worries, <a class="color-green" href="lostpw.php">click here</a> to reset your password.</p>
            </form>
```

---

This is my checkuser.php code:

```
<?
/* Check User Script */
session_start();  // Start Session

include 'db.php';
// Convert to simple variables
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if((!$username) || (!$password)){
    /*echo "Please enter ALL of the information! <br />";*/
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Please enter both username and password.");</script>';
    include 'login_form.php';
    exit();
}

// Convert password to md5 hash
$password = md5($password);

// check if the user info validates the db
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' AND activated='1'");
$login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if($login_check > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    foreach( $row AS $key => $val ){
        $$key = stripslashes( $val );
    }
        // Register some session variables!

        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
        $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
        $_SESSION['email_address'] = $email_address;


        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_login=now() WHERE userid='$userid'");

        header("Location: login_success.php");

    }
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("You could not be logged in! Either the username and password do not match or you have not validated your membership.     Please try again.");</script>';
    include 'login_form.php';
}
?>
```

---

This is how my member page starts (login_success.php):

```
<?
include 'db.php';
session_start();
//checked whether the user is logged in or not 

$user = $_SESSION['username'];

if($_SESSION['username'])
{
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
header("Location: login_form.php");
exit();
}

mysql_select_db('ibsclientlogin');

$sql="SELECT * FROM users";

$records=mysql_query($sql);

?>
```

---

This is the section of the page where I display the db data of the logged in user:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
            while ($users=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){ ?>

        <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 mobile-pad'>
            <h3>Client Information</h3>
            <ul>
                <label>Contact First Name:</label> <?php echo $users['first_name']; ?><br>
                <label>Contact Last Name:</label> <?php echo $users['last_name']; ?><br>
                <hr>
                <label>Company:</label> <?php echo $users['company']; ?><br>
                <hr>
                <label>Email:</label> <?php echo $users['email_address']; ?><br>
                <label>Phone:</label> <?php echo $users['phone']; ?><br>
                <hr>
                <label>Username:</label> <?php echo $users['username']; ?><br><br>               
                <!--<a target="_blank" class="btn btn-success" href="">Change My Password</a>-->
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6'>
            <h3>Contract Information</h3> 
            <ul>
                <label>Contract Start Date:</label> <?php echo $users['contract_start']; ?><br>
                <label>Contract Expiration Date:</label> <?php echo $users['contract_end']; ?><br><br>
                <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-success" href="mailto:sales@ibusinessresources.com?subject=iBusiness Resources Client Renewal Request - <?php echo $users['company']; ?>">Renew Me Now</a>           
            </ul>

            <hr>
            <h3>My Documents</h3> 
            <h5>
                <ul>
                    <label>Agreement:</label> <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $users['filename']; ?>"</a>Click to Download<br>

                </ul>
            </h5>
            <hr>
            <h3>Need Help?</h3>
                <h5>
                    <ul>
                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i><a href="tel:12109606788"> (210) 960-6788</a><br><br>
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><a href="mailto:sales@ibusinessresources.com"> sales@ibusinessresources.com</a><br>

                    </ul>
                </h5>

        </div>
    <?php } ?>          
    </div>
```

But the result of this is my member page displays the two sample users on my database.  I am a rookie that has put this code together from "hatchling" code around the internet.  It seems I'm close but this part has got me stumped.

Here is a screen shot of the member page with a loop of both users data.

[Screen shot of member page after log in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZfrG.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Can you please rephrase your question? Your sql query selects all rows in the users table, are there just the two sample users in that table? What is your desired result? Also, you are using depreciated mysql functions. You should use mysqli, and you are not escaping your data so you are vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. In this short example you have a number of dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) coming from a reckless lack of [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a successful login, in login_success.php you request all user records from db:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users";
```

which is not what you want to do.

After a successful login you make the decisions of what is the privilege going to be, of the login being successful. Put your business logic at that point.

eg. as stated already

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
```

Comment: You can't just throw arbitrary junk in the query and hope it works, that needs escaping. Who knows what `$_SESSION['username']` contains.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so you've got a few different problems here.

Firstly, you are trying to check a session variable $_SESSION['username'] which you never create - on your login page you are defining:

```
    $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
    $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
    $_SESSION['email_address'] = $email_address;
```

But never username - so firstly, you need to add $_SESSION['username'] = $username; to your login script.

Secondly, you are then checking here that it *does* exist - presumably you actually mean to check it doesn't exist:

```
//Currently, this says if $_SESSION['username'] does exist, then send them abck to the login screen!!
if($_SESSION['username'])
{
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
header("Location: login_form.php");
exit();
}
```

Instead, the if line should be

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){ ....
```

Then, as pointed above above, your select statement will fetch all users, so you need to add a WHERE clause to only get the current user:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
```

That shoudl get you back on the right track!

Comment: You can't just throw arbitrary junk in the query and hope it works, that needs escaping. Who knows what `$_SESSION['username']` contains.

Comment: Fantastic. Got it working.  I am aware of the vulnerabilities but this is storing public information for ease of clients.  Now that the feature is functional I will get educated on the updated PHP coding and update accordingly,  Thanks for your help and input.